# why I can use a constructor injection without using @autowired

Tags: spring, spring-boot

it's a spring in action 5th 's example in page

OrderController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/orders")
@SessionAttributes("order")
public class OrderController {

    private OrderRepository orderRepo;

    public OrderController(OrderRepository orderRepo) {
        this.orderRepo = orderRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping("/current")
    public String orderForm() {
        return "orderForm";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processOrder(@Valid Order order, Errors errors, SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "orderForm";
        }

        orderRepo.save(order);
        sessionStatus.setComplete();

        return "redirect:/";
    }

}
```

OrderRepository.java

```
public interface OrderRepository {

  Order save(Order order);

}
```

and why can i use this code without adding a @Autowired
thanks for help.

```
public OrderController(OrderRepository orderRepo) {
        this.orderRepo = orderRepo;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its spring's feature.

There was a resolved [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16883) opened for this

Long story short:

If the class has only one constructor(and in java, once you create a constructor, a default no-arg constructor doesn't exist anymore)  and is annotated as `@Component`, then spring can "understand" that calling this constructor is the only way to instantiate the bean. So it introspects its parameters and injects what needed. 
All this happens without really specifying the `@Autowired`.

This works since Spring 4.3 RC1: See [Release notes](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/06/spring-framework-4-3-goes-rc1)

Comment: thanks for your answer, it really helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OrderRepository instance should has been created (via @Configuration or XML) before pass to OrderController constructor. In this case, @Autowired annotations is not necessary.